# Subroutes or nested routes in Ionic/Angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm curios how to achieve the following:

I have a tree structure: Senior Managers -> Managers -> Associate Managers -> Consultants

1. Managers shows a list of Senior Managers `/managers`
2. The route `managers/:id` selects a certain manager of course
3. Now managers have associated staff and timetables for example. I want a stable navigation at this level, where a user can choose between staff `/managers/:id/staff` and timetables `/managers/:id/timetables`.

So I thought about having a usual

```
<ion-app>

  <ion-router-outlet id="main-content"></ion-router-outlet>

</ion-app>
```

Where managers-route and the managers-id-route is defined.

Inside the page, where managers-id-route leads to, the must be something like the nav and second router-outlet right?

```
<nav>Static Nav</nav>
<ion-router-outlet id="aux-content"></ion-router-outlet>
```

Or is my way of thinking wrong? Where can I see such a thing by example?

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with reusable components. And then with each selection just call your api. Here is some sudo code:

app.html

```
<ng-container *ngIf="seniorManagerData$ | async as smd">
  <app-senior-manager-view [inputData]="smd">
  </app-senior-manager-view>
</ng-container>
```

app-senior-manager.page.html

```
<ng-container *ngIf="managerData$ | async as md">
  <app-manager-view [inputData]="md" [seniorManager]="seniorManagerSelection" *ngIf="seniorManagerSelection">
  </app-manager-view>
</ng-container>
```

app-manager.page.html

```
<ng-container *ngIf="associateManagerData$ | async as amd">
  <app-associate-manager-view [associateManager]="associateManagerSelection" *ngIf="associateManagerSelection" [inputData]="amd">
  </app-associate-manager-view>
</ng-container>
```

app-associate-manager.page.html

```
<ng-container *ngIf="consultantData$ | async as cd">
  <app-consultant-view [consultant]="consulantSelection" *ngIf="consultantSelection" [inputData]="cd">
</ng-container>
```

Each component could have an api service injected into it which would call your back end data to load the appropriate info. No need to use ionic/angular routes at all.

So some pseudo code again along the lines of:

```
seniorManagerData$ :Observable<unknown>;

seniorManagerSelection: unknown;

constructor( myApi: ApiService) {}

viewWillEnter() {
   //do this within a loading controller, don't block your UI
   this.seniorManagerData$ = this.myApi.getSeniorManagerData();
}

onSeniorManagerSelection(mySelection: unknown) {
   this.seniorManagerSelection = mySelection;
}
```

Again this is just pseudo code which probably needs adjustment within an actual project. But hopefully this gives some idea.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I am looking for a more plain solution. If that amount of logic is need for a simple ordering and routing task, I consider not using ionic.

Comment: This is not an issue with ionic. This is how Angular handles routing.

Comment: Maybe. A simple solution was just to enable and disable the menu on certain routes/pages: `this.menu.enable(false);`